# Texture of model lighted up without light

Tags: texturing, uv, light, lighting

I deleted all the lights in my scene. However even without light some of my textures are uniformily "lighted up", or at least visibleas you can see on the picture. [image] The visible textures are psd files I put via texture nodes.
This makes my textures very flat looking. Any idea what causes this and how to get rid of it?

Here is a picture of the texture nodes. The two circled in red are the ones that appeared "lighted up" in render view. [image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome. It looks as if you may have plugged your image-texture nodes straight into the material output, without a shader (e.g. 'Principled')  in the way, to govern the light-response of the surface. If you're asking a question about materials, it might make sense to include an image of your material nodes.

Comment: Hi  @RobinBetts thank you for your quick reaction. I added a picture of my nodes. The problematic textures are indeed directly connected to the output (well there is a mix shader node in between). I have a principled but it is connected separately from my problematic textures. What type of node could I had and with which parameters?

Comment: Assuming the psds are  of  the desired diffuse color, you could, for example, plug the image (or a mix of your images) into the 'Base Color' input of a Principled shader. Colors are colors; they are parameters to shaders, they are not shaders themselves. (Although Blender has the default 'flat' shader you are currently getting, if you don't specify one)

Comment: If you directly plug the Image Texture into the Output it won't work in Cycles and it will act as if there was an Emission node in Eevee, so as everybody says you need to use a Diffuse after the Image Texture (or a Principled BSDF, that will act as a Diffuse by default)

Answer (score 4):

**The problem is thts you connected the *Textures* directly to the *Mix Shader Node*.**

To fix the problem you should add a *BSDF Node* between: the *texture Node* connects to the *BSDf*'s color socket and the *BSDF* connects to the mix node.

I would use the principled BSDF but you can
use any one.